# R - rgdal ERRO in shp file - Layer

Tags: r, runtime-error, layer, shapefile, rgdal

I am trying to open a SHP file in RStudio using the rgdal package to make maps using the ggplot.

Command:

```
install.packages(rgdal, dependencies = T)
library(rgdal)
pb <- readOGR("C:/Users/Leanderson Silvestre/Desktop/MapasR", "pbshape")
```

But, i've got an error after the command:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
```

Any advice, guys ?

The archive is inside this brazilian geographic shapes governamental site (i only change the name of the `.shp` file): [here](ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2013/PB/pb_municipios.zip)

Answer (score 0):

i got it!

If anyone have this same problem, you need to **extract** your files direct in **the directory of interrest**. If you extract only the `.shp` file or extract in a different folder and after this copy to your directory of interrest, the error will persist.